# New value not getting updated in the div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a pop up from where the value is selected. When I select the value the control goes to server via ajax call and in callback method I have the HTML page generated.

I've tried to set the value to div like this to a div.

```
$("#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName").replaceWith($('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html());
```

When I use the above line, the value is getting set to the `div` for the first time but after that, whenever I select a new value and the ajax call happens, the value is not getting set and the whatever I had set for the first time remains.

UPDATE:

The ajax method I use to set the values:

```
function getCustomerDetails(customerName,viewName) {
    var global = window.document

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
            url: viewName,
            data: {
                id: customerName
            },
            success: function (msg) {


                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName").innerHTML = $('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html();

                alert($('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html());
                alert($('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_PackingMethod', msg).html());

                $("#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName").replaceWith($('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html());
                $("#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_PackingMethod").replaceWith($('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_PackingMethod', msg).html());

            }
        });

}
```

How do I update the new value to the div?

Comment: post your ajax request code.

Comment: do you really using that long div id `#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName` ??

Comment: Console.log this result $('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg) and tell what is .

Comment: alert( $('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html()); when i use this i gives me the value selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the fact that your AJAX works the first time but not after `.replaceWith()` it's probably because all event handlers are removed when you replace a node with a piece of HTML fragment.

You should register your event handlers using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or `.delegate()` on nodes that will not get removed throughout the lifetime of your app.

Let's assume you have this structure:

```
<div id="mybase">
   <div class="mysel">
       <select name="test"><option /> ... </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

And assume you register event handlers like this:

```
$('#mybase input[name="test"]').change(function() {
    // replace $('#mybase .mysel') with something that has the same dropdown
});
```

Now your event handler would be gone and any changes in the dropdown are not firing your event handler.

Instead you could do this:

```
$('#mybase').on('change', 'input[name="test"]', function() {
    // replace $('#mybase .mysel') with something that has the same dropdown
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: alert( $('#CIMtrek_dvDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName', msg).html()); when i printed it gives me the value selected

Comment: @Anto Thanks, but that code gets run because of an event right? So what's the event?

Comment: onclick of the item listed ;   `getCustomerDetails(Select.options[i].value,'CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_ShipmentsFormCustomerDetails');`

Comment: I call a method in which the this method is called `getCustomerDetails(Select.options[i].value,'CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_ShipmentsF‌​ormCustomerDetails');`

Comment: @Anto So if your `onchange` doesn't fire the second time, you have to use something like `$(element).on('click', selector, function() { ... })` where `element` is a node that will never be removed or replaced and `selector` is the relative query from `element` that will be used to fire your event handler.

Comment: thanks for the commets, could you explaint this `$(element).on('click', selector, function() { ... })`

Comment: @Anto Updated my answer, hope that helps.